# Python pandas - unique function returning unexpected output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in a csv file with 100 records as Status with values as ['Active', 'Cancelled', 'Cancelled - Gap in Status'].
I want to get unique values of this column.
My code is as below:

```
df=pd.read_pickle(data_frame.pickle')

status = df['Status']

print(pd.unique(status))

print(len(pd.unique(status)))

Output:
['Active', 'Cancelled']

2
```

What am I missing here?

Sample Data:
+--------------------+--------+--------------+-------+---------------------------+
|       Stage        |   ID   |     Name     | State |          Status           |
+--------------------+--------+--------------+-------+---------------------------+
| 123456Peter Grunt  | 123456 | Peter Grunt  | DE    | Active                    |
| 123456Peter Grunt  | 123456 | Peter Grunt  | NY    | Cancelled                 |
| 123456Peter Grunt  | 123456 | Peter Grunt  | CA    | Cancelled                 |
| 123456Peter Grunt  | 123456 | Peter Grunt  | IA    | Cancelled                 |
| 123456Peter Grunt  | 123456 | Peter Grunt  | WA    | Cancelled                 |
| 123456Peter Grunt  | 123456 | Peter Grunt  | DE    | Cancelled                 |
| 123456Peter Grunt  | 123456 | Peter Grunt  | NC    | Active                    |
| 123457William Bert | 123457 | William Bert | NY    | Active                    |
| 123457William Bert | 123457 | William Bert | SD    | Active                    |
| 123457William Bert | 123457 | William Bert | WA    | Cancelled - Gap in Status |
| 123457William Bert | 123457 | William Bert | CA    | Active                    |
| 123457William Bert | 123457 | William Bert | IA    | Active                    |
| 123457William Bert | 123457 | William Bert | WA    | Active                    |
| 123457William Bert | 123457 | William Bert | DE    | Active                    |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | AL    | Active                    |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | AK    | Cancelled                 |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | MD    | Cancelled                 |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | MA    | Cancelled                 |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | AK    | Cancelled                 |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | NY    | Cancelled - Gap in Status |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | LA    | Cancelled                 |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | SD    | Cancelled                 |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | WA    | Cancelled                 |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | CA    | Cancelled                 |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | IA    | Active                    |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | WA    | Active                    |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | DE    | Active                    |
| 123458John Grand   | 123458 | John Grand   | AL    | Active                    |
+--------------------+--------+--------------+-------+---------------------------+

Comment: What is expected output? Do you need `status.drop_duplicates()` ?

Comment: drop_duplicates() is also giving only Active and Cancelled. I am expecting Cancelled - Gap in Status in the output as well.

Comment: please provide an example dataframe. Your code worked ok for  my sample dataframe.

Comment: check your csv, are you absolutely sure that there is at least 1 'Cancelled - Gap in Status' entry?

Answer (score 0):

There should be an error in your input data. As concerning your question regarding error and your provided code, it returns expected result from my side:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Status': ['Active', 'Cancelled', 'Cancelled - Gap in Status']})
print(df)


                     Status
0                     Active
1                  Cancelled
2  Cancelled - Gap in Status

status = df['Status']
print(pd.unique(status))
print(len(pd.unique(status)))
```

Which return:

```
['Active' 'Cancelled' 'Cancelled - Gap in Status']
3
```